# How to upload image into a folder in firebase storage

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm writing an app that selects an image from gallery and uuploads into a folder in firestore.

```
await Future.forEach(_paths.entries, (v) async {
                        String uid = Uuid().v1();
                        StorageReference imgReference = 
_storageReference.child("Form2").child(uid);
                        StorageUploadTask task = imgReference.putFile(
                            File(v.value)
                        );
                        StorageTaskSnapshot downloadURL = await 
task.onComplete;
                        String value = await downloadURL.ref.getDownloadURL();
                    paths[uid] = value;
                  }
```

The image is not uploading into the folder. But it is uploading into the firestore directly

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to specify the folder name in .child(). Like : `.child("/$folder").child("$fileName")`.

Example :

```
    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('/$folder').child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putData(imageData);
    print('Upload triggered in the background.');
    ...

    return await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is a code that upload an image with its name to firebase. Sliderutils is a class that has a getName() and getImageUrl() function (getters and setters).

```
StorageReference Ref= 
mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+"."+getPath(filePath));

        mStorageTask = Ref.putFile(filePath)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new 
OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image uploaded successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        SliderUtils sliderUtils = new SliderUtils(EditTextName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                        mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(sliderUtils);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image upload failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Accounting to firebase docs the easiest way is to add a child to storage reference:

```
uploadImageToFireStore(String foldername, String fileName) async {
  // Upload image to firebase storage
  final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("$foldername/$fileName");
  await storageRef.putFile(imgPath!);
}
```

This function receive a folder name and file name to upload the file.
Hope this will help
Good luck